# Clarification Question from Berger's Statistical Decision Theory (Chapter 1, Exercise 12 a))

Tags: expected-value, decision-theory, risk

I have a CS background with intro stats courses, and currently, I am working through Berger's Statistical Decision Theory (the theoretical questions).
I'd like to ask a clarification question: this is question 12 from Chapter 1:

Consider a decision problem and decision rule $\delta$ for which
$$\mathbb{E}[(L(\theta, \delta(X)) - R(\theta, \delta))^2] \le k < \infty$$

Imagine a sequence of repetitions of the decision problem, where the parameters $\theta_i$ can change and the data $X^{(i)}$ (from the density $f(x|\theta_i)$) are independent. Show that, if $R(\theta, \delta) < \bar{R}$ for all $\theta$, then

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}L(\theta_i, \delta(X^{(i)})) \le \bar{R}$$

with probability one for any sequence $(\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots).$

Now, the book defines
$$R(\theta, \delta) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}^X[L(\theta, \delta(X))]$$, which is the expectation over $X$ for a specific value $\theta$. So I see that this makes the first expression mean that variance of $X$ for a specific value $\theta$ is finite and less than equal to some value $k$.

It's also clear to me that I will need to use the Law of Large Numbers. But I am confused by $\bar{R}$. It is not defined in the book, but obviously, the bar generally means the 'average' (or mean, or expected value). So my question is what would be that average over? As $R(\theta,\delta)$ is already defined as the expectation over X, my only guess is that it could be the expectation over the $\theta$'s, but that's precisely the expression on the left hand side of the second expression.

Comment: I think it is just a notation (you can safely replace it with $K$, representing any constant, or fixed random variable, depending on the context), "bar" doesn't always connote "average".

Comment: In that case, it's a confusing notation, but I think you are right, thank you.